# Cropped graph when using log scale in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, cdf

I'm using matplotlib to plot a pandas dataframe. I want to use log scale on the Y axis, the problem is that when I do so, the graph is cropped (values in Y axis range from 0 to 1). I'm already using log scale on the X axis without problems.

This is the graph with linear scale:

```
ax = df2.plot(kind = 'line', x = 'priceUSD', y = 'cumulative_probability')

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel("Precio medio de los activos")
ax.set_ylabel("Probabilidad")
plt.legend(["Todos los activos"])
```

[image]

If I use log scale on the Y axis 0 values are not shown:

```
ax = df2.plot(kind = 'line', x = 'priceUSD', y = 'cumulative_probability')

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel("Precio medio de los activos")
ax.set_ylabel("Probabilidad")
plt.legend(["Todos los activos"])
```

[image]

df2 looks like this:

[image]

I want the plot to look similar to the following image:
[image]

I've been experimenting with `set_yticks` and `set_major_formatter` but no luck so far.

Comment: Could you please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's unclear how `df2` looks like from the question.

Comment: Sure @medium-dimensional, I added a capture to the question.

Comment: You probably want to [ax.set_ylim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html) to set the y interval.

Comment: The problem was that log 0 is undefined so 0 values are not shown. I added 10e-11 to 0 values and the graph is not cropped anymore. Thank you!